# Navigation through CustomUiview Class in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have created a custom class and assign to uiview.. that view is opened in uiviewcontroller.. but the problem is that..from this custom view navigation does not works....

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code


        self.view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 250, 503)];
        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

        UIView *subView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 100)];
        [self.view addSubview:subView];

        CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];

        bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 99, subView.frame.size.width, 1.0f);

        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8f
                                                         alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

        [subView.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];


        UIImageView *profimg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 60, 60)];
        profimg.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        profimg.layer.cornerRadius=profimg.frame.size.width/2;
        profimg.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

        UILabel *lbluname=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 15, 160, 25)];
        lbluname.text=@"User Name";
        lbluname.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        [subView addSubview:lbluname];


        UILabel *lblEmail=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 40, 170, 25)];
        lblEmail.text=@"darshit.infusion@gmail.com";
        lblEmail.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        [subView addSubview:lblEmail];


        UILabel *lblpwdVerify=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 65, 160, 25)];
        lblpwdVerify.text=@"Verify your profile";
        lblpwdVerify.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        [subView addSubview:lblpwdVerify];


        [subView addSubview:profimg];

        UITableView *tbl=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 250, 400)];
        tbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        tbl.delegate=self;
        tbl.dataSource=self;


        [self.view addSubview:tbl];

        self.bounds=self.view.bounds;


        [self addSubview:self.view];
        self.view.frame =  CGRectMake(-250, 65, 250, 503);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 65, 250, 503);
        }];



        listMenuSide=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Live Radar",@"Online",@"Become a Premium",@"History",@"Message",@"Advance Search",@"Match",@"News",@"Edit Profile",@"Find Me Good",@"I Think Good",@"Sign Out",nil];

        listImg=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"radar.gif",@"online.png",@"spade.png",@"visitor.png",@"msg.png",@"search.png",@"match.png",@"news.png",@"edit_profile.png",@"like.png",@"findgood.png",@"signoff.png",nil];


        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:68/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:68/255.0 alpha:1];
        tbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:68/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:68/255.0 alpha:1];
        subView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:68/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:68/255.0 alpha:1];





    }
    return self;
}
-(IBAction)clknav:(id)sender{

    ProfileView *paaa=[[ProfileView alloc]init];
    [paaa didSelectRow:0];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

}
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)ViewCustom:(UIView *)view{


}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 58.0;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [listMenuSide count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SideViewCcellCustom *cell = (SideViewCcellCustom  *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"SideViewCcellCustom" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }


    cell.lightningImageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
    cell.lightningImageView.animationRepeatCount = 5; //default is 0, which repeats indefinitely
    [cell.lightningImageView startAnimating];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:68/255.0 green:68/255.0 blue:68/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.lightningImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[listImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.lbltxt.text=[listMenuSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //cell.textLabel.text=[listMenuSide objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    OGViewController *homeViewController = [[OGViewController alloc] init];

    ProfileView *paaa=[[ProfileView alloc]init];
    [paaa didSelectRow:0];




//   we can't use navigation controller here....

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];



}
```

i have used custom navigation also.. bat it is not work in uiview

Comment: How have you presented this view controller?  Have you pushed it in a navigation controller?

Comment: Is this code in a view or a view controller? Is self.navigationController non-nil?

Comment: this is not view controller.this is Uiview only show in deferent class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use nsnotification... it'll work nicely with this type of problem..

Answer (score 0):

navigationController is property of `UIViewController` not `UIView` so you can't call

```
[self.navigationController ...]
```

from your view class.
You have to implement some delegate.